# Is it possible to export as gltf with animated textures?

Tags: animation, uv, gltf

Im working on a model and have set the texture of the computer screen to an image sequence. However, I can play the animation just fine and the sequence works well, however, when exported as a GLTF there is no image sequence and stays on the first image while everything else that is animated does play. Is it even possible to export it with a working image sequence? Help much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: No, only LocRotScale and shapekey weights can be animated. The only way you could do it is the "stop motion" trick (where you animate scale 0<->1 to show/hide objects) but that's hard to do.